How to avoid stdout/stderr buffering in ros launch for the purpose of using progress bars?
NOTE: I didn't put many links because of this rule of not having reputation to post more than 8 links :)
I have a very rudimentary necessity: to print a simple progress bar to the standard output in a ROS 2 context. I only want to use the progress bar from p-ranav/indicators.
The Hello World application works when running the node as ros2 node run progress_bar but is impossible to do work when using a launch system.
The reason I could find lies within the internal buffering of the stdout/stderr :
ros2/launch/launch/launch/actions/execute_local.py#L222-L223
        self.__stdout_buffer = io.StringIO()
        self.__stderr_buffer = io.StringIO()

That only gets flushed at the very end of the action:
ros2/launch/launch/launch/actions/execute_local.py#L697-L700
            flush_buffers_method = self.__flush_buffers

            OnProcessExit(
                target_action=self,
                on_exit=flush_buffers_method,
            ),

This is not a problem when using the standard logging tools RCLUTILS, but I couldn't find a way to control the return carriage, and it's impractical to write a progress bar from scratch when I only want to use an open-source one.
Toy example
This is the example that it's only working when not using the launch system (please let me know if you need me to create a GitHub repo to reproduce the issue)
// Taken from https://github.com/p-ranav/indicators
#include "indicators.hpp"

#include <chrono>
#include <cstdio>
#include <rclcpp/rclcpp.hpp>
#include <thread>

class ProgressBar {
public:
  void run() {
    for (int i = 0; i <= total_; ++i) {
      bar_.set_progress(i);
      std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(10));
      fprintf(stdout, "\r");
    }
    bar_.mark_as_completed();
  }

private:
  int total_{100};
  indicators::ProgressBar bar_{
      indicators::option::ForegroundColor{indicators::Color::green},
      indicators::option::ShowPercentage{true},
      indicators::option::ShowElapsedTime{true},
      indicators::option::ShowRemainingTime{true},
      indicators::option::MaxProgress{total_}};
};

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  rclcpp::init(argc, argv);
  std::make_shared<ProgressBar>()->run();
  rclcpp::shutdown();
  return 0;
}

Output of ros2 run node progress_bar
t0:

t1:

Output of ros2 launch ./launch.py
def generate_launch_description():

    node = Node(
        package="progress_bar",
        executable="progress_bar_node",
        name="progress_bar_node",
        output="screen",
        emulate_tty=True,
    )
    return LaunchDescription([node])

Empty until the process finishes
to:

t1:

Things I've tried
I tried to force std::flush to happen and touched all env variables, but nothing seems to be working due to the reasons mentioned above. The stdout/stderr simply gets buffered in the ros2 launch system.
export RCUTILS_LOGGING_BUFFERED_STREAM=0
export RCUTILS_LOGGING_USE_STDOUT=1
export RCUTILS_COLORIZED_OUTPUT=1

I also hacked the execute_local and add a self.__flush_buffers at the end of each on_output_method, but this prints a new line at each iteartion
Related issues

https://github.com/ros2/launch/issues/188
https://github.com/ros2/rcutils/issues/70
https://answers.ros.org/question/332829/no-stdout-logging-output-in-ros2-using-launch/

